# How to change the case of submitted value of dropdown in Formidable Wordpress Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, formidable

How to change the case of dropdown values in Formidable Wordpress Plugin?

FYI - Data is populated on the website via CSV using the Import/Export option of Formidable Plugin. Data is huge (1 million), so changing the case in the data itself is not a good option.

When the form is getting submitted, the value of Code Dropdown getting saved as "Forex", but I want value will get saved as "forex". Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Following things I have tried:

1. Created New Custom CSS

[image: Created New Custom CSS]

2. Added this custom CSS into Lookup Field as:

[image: Added this custom CSS into Lookup Field]

3. Also tried to use Customize HTML from FORM Setting as:

[image: Tried to use Customize HTML from FORM Setting]

4. Here in the customize HTML code, I am unable to understand, how to tweak it, so that submitted value will be in lowercase.

[image: Customize HTML code]

Comment: It would be nice if you add more insight to your question like a link to Formidable plugin or a screenshot and finally any solution what you've tried to solve your problem. We intent to use stackoverflow as a resource to learn from others challenges and expand our vision by trying to empathize others point of views. More insight in your question would attract more users to try answering.

Comment: That would make sense. Thanks for advising. Here I have updated the approach and screenshots. I would appreciate it if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer on how to do this, Formidable provides the ability to do this by using seperate field values for the saved data.

Directly under the Dropdown Options you need to tick the checkbox:
*Use separate values*

Once this is ticked you will see an additional option for each field for the submitted value. That way you can enter the lowercase value you need in the save option field.

[image: Separate Values field options]

Note you may need a Formidable base license to see this option.

More info here:
https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/separate-values/